# How do I bypass the error 'Org cache is only supported in Data Silo tests' in a test class that must use the seeAllData=true setting

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I have written a batch class that uses the Metadata API and finds old reports and moves them to a purge folder. This works fine.  However, test classes apparently can't create reports and they don't have access to existing reports without using the seeAllData=true setting.  Using that setting gives a 'Org cache is only supported in Data Silo tests' error.  I see no way through a test class to turn off org caching.

How do I get past this?

Comment: You can use the `Test.isRunningTest()` to get the context and not run the org caching code in the actual class.

Comment: Yes - but test classes can mock `Report` objects so your mock metadata API callout can return mock Reports.  There are extremely few reasons to use SeeAllData=true (ConnectApi being one of them).  Always look for a way to mock sobjects via selector / service layers when you can't do DML

Comment: A test class can mock report metadata but it can't create a record in the Report sobject.  The start method query in my batch class is selecting from the Report object.